# How to design a boost converter using SiC mosfet in LTspice

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, boost

I am very new to LTspice and I am designing a boost converter using a SiC mosfet but I am not getting the result. My parameters are:

- Vin = 363 V
- Vout = 500 V
- Frequency = 10 kHz

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Can you run a time domain simulation and show the graphs of what you are getting. Some of your connections seem "iffy", particularly on the MOSFET and capacitor C2, and the inductor which is labeled just "L". Do you really have 2 x 100 mF capacitors in series on the output? Did you mean microfarads (uF) ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZcmg.png here is result after changing some parameters but i wonder it its correct

Comment: Are you getting "the result"?

Comment: I think its quite right as compare to the result I was getting earlier but I am not sure.

Comment: It seems reasonable to me, given the component values, and open-loop control. Whether that's useful for some underlying purpose, we of course cannot know. Do you know if the capacitor, Tc, or both changes made the difference?

Comment: Yeah it did earlier I was getting a straight linear output which was unreasonable but when I changed the capacitor value and added Tc value(as Specified by the SiC mosfet manual) I got this results which is quite ok. But do you think its taking more time to reach the output value or is this okay?

Comment: The initial output surge to nearly 1 kV indicates that there could be a problem unless the PWM drive signal starts with lower duty cycle. Check the peak current in the inductor. If it saturates, the current could reach damaging levels. Of course, real world behavior will be much different.

Comment: Like I said, open-loop control; which is to say, no "control" at all. A real current-mode controller will fully constrain inductor current, and make voltage rise and overshoot much more reasonably defined.  Consequently, gate PWM will vary during startup and in operation, as one would expect.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzoIc.png I changed my inductor value and got this result as shown above. Can you help me point out what mistake I am doing.

Comment: If you allow the simulation to run for a couple hundred ms, you will see a damped oscillation that may settle at your desired output voltage. And you can set the plot window to start at, say, 500 ms and stop at 600 ms. You can also scale the Y axis to see the waveform and ripple current. You might be able to add a high side current monitor and have it turn off the MOSFET until it settles. But that's what a $2 controller IC does very nicely. ;)

Comment: So should I add that controller IC your saying to turn off the MOSFET.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to invalidate existing answers -- if you have a new question now, you can ask it separately.  Please include all meaningful details, such as: what you expect from the simulation, what your allowable input and output ripple voltage/current and frequency are, what operating voltage/current ranges are, what the source and load characteristics are, etc.

Comment: Oh okay my mistake. I am using this site for the first time so I don't know the rules. So, now should I revert back to the original question?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect Tc needs to be defined.  Please read the manual for the SPICE model you've installed and check if this is the case.

The capacitance is also suspiciously large.  Did you mean to type millifarad (mF)?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzoIc.png yeah this one is the changed version of the simulation but still something is wrong.

Comment: You reduced the inductance by 10x and got approximately a 10x increase in startup current at fixed PWM; what's the issue? You'll have to be more specific. Perhaps you should begin evaluating controller ICs?

Comment: I am actually trying to build a boost converter using SiC mosfet for a PV module and I tried doing it but I was getting a straight linear increase in the output voltage so, i tried first to build this boost converter but since I am new to LTspice I tried referring to some videos but my output is not very clean.

Comment: I see. Then you might like to model the panel impedance (and input filter) as well as add a controller.

Comment: Can you refer me to some sites or videos anything from where I can learn.

Comment: That is out of scope here but you might ask a new question on that.

Comment: In above output do you think i should change some parameters values so as to make the output little smooth?

Comment: I have no idea what your ripple specifications (or anything else about this project) is.

Comment: @ABJ, It appears that you have at least two or three major projects going on. (1) You want to make a PV module. (2) You want to learn how to use LTspice to assist in the design process. (3) You want to learn the basics (and finer points) of switching supply design. In addition, you have constrained the design parameters to use a SiC MOSFET. For each of these, IMHO, you will need to learn how to create a detailed design spec, or set clear goals. Probably none of those can be formed into an answerable question, per site guidelines.

Comment: yeah you got me correct and I have a submission tomorrow.